# Missing iCloud logging "Using local storage: 0"

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I'm creating iCloud enabled storage following Apple's [instruction her](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html)e.
However, I don't see "Using local storage: 1" or "Using local storage: 0" being printed on the console using the latest xCode 6.1.1 for iOS8. Did Apple drop these prints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling iCloud is not sufficient, "iCloud Documents" must also get enabled to see "Using local storage: x" prints.